# Error when generating release AAB in React Native

Tags: react-native, gradle, google-play, gradlew, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to publish my React Native app to the Google Play Store. I've generated a private signing key using `keytool` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin`, and I've moved it to my project folder under `android/app`.

I set up my gradle variables under `android/gradle.properties`:

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

I've edited the file `android/app/build.gradle` and put the following text under `signingConfigs`:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to generate the release AAB using `cd android` `./gradlew bundleRelease`, I get multiple errors:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Scope\android\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: 
resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.authentication:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yo usay the keystore is under `android/app` but the `MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE` doesn't have that in its path?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue by rebuilding my app using `npx react-native init projectName` and copying in my project files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not about how you provided the environment values at all.

It is stated in the error that:

```
error: 
resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.authentication:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
```

So you are missing the `ic_launcher_round` icon in your project

Comment: This was probably it. Thank you!